# Finding the Thevenin Voltage with respect to terminals A and B using Nodal analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

Was doing this problem and I got -1V for the Thevenin voltage, but my lecturer got 5V. The resistors are actually measured in Ohms and not kilo ohms, my lecturer made a mistake. I was wondering if she got it wrong or if I did it wrong. [image]

Comment: If the resistors are in ohm, your lecturer is correct. If the resistors are in k ohm, there are some really large voltages in play!

Answer (score -1):

The first simplification that comes to my mind is the following, moving from your schematic on the left directly to the one on the right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f84wjR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To compute the difference between **a** and **b**, I can just say that \$V_b=0\:\text{V}\$ and focus only on \$V_a\$, with reference to it. I'm allowed to pick any node I want and call it the ground reference, or \$0\:\text{V}\$. And you can easily see that, above.

Also, there's no need to "bus power around." So the \$+12\:\text{V}\$ supply rail can be simply annotated rather than showing wires, which will only serve to confuse you during analysis.

Finally, when a current source sinks or sources from a voltage source, you can just "lose the connection." It will distract you. But it doesn't achieve anything, as the voltage source effectively just a dead short from the current source's point of view. You could just as well have run it to ground. So scratch it. It just makes things look more complex than they are, keeping the wire. You can see I've just removed it and allowed the current source to sink into outer space, so far as I care.

Now, you should be able to see the following, in quick succession:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftk5hz.png)</sup>

First, compute the Thevenin of \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ as a voltage divider. Then combine the two series resistances.

Next, compute the Thevenin of \$R_1\$ and \$R_{_\text{TOT}}\$ between the two voltage sources. The result should be easily seen, as shown.

Finally, you start with \$9\:\text{V}\$ and pull \$2\:\text{A}\$ through \$R_{_\text{TOT}}=2\:\Omega\$, which drops \$2\:\text{A}\cdot 2\:\Omega=4\:\text{V}\$ from the \$9\:\text{V}\$, yielding \$5\:\text{V}\$.

As there's no current in \$R_5\$, and therefore no voltage drop across it, the output at \$V_a\$ is the same, or \$V_a=5\:\text{V}\$.

The output impedance can be seen by:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiVRYk.png)</sup>

It should be \$4\:\Omega\$.

I'm sure you already know how to find the maximum power load resistor, from there, and can compute the dissipation.

Answer (score -2):

The Thevenin equivalent voltage is indeed 5V.

To find Thevenin equiv. voltage, you simply calculate the voltage you would get when the output is open.

In this case, assume the voltage at the node that connects the three resistors is V, then the current flowing in the three resistors can be expressed as the attached photo (assuming certain direction of current flow).

By using the condition that the current in and current out at the left node between the current source and the top 4 Ohm resistor adds up to zero (KCL), you will find the unknown voltage at the central node V is 5.5V. By knowing the voltage, you can work out the current through each resistor and that the voltage drop at the 2 Ohm resistor will be 0.5V. Thus the voltage at point a is equal to 5 Volt (assuming b is at ground).

Note that the 2 Ohm resistor at the output point a does not play a role since no current flows though it when the output is open, thus voltage drop is zero.

[image]